# Angular 2, in route change the scripts don't work

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am building an Angular 2 project, in which I have a login screen. When the login is successful then user proceeds to home screen. I have added my css and javascript files in index.html The problem is that after redirection to homescreen, the scripts are not loaded and I have to refresh the page to get them work. What should I do? How to make them run in every route change?

Ps. these files are needed for styling, so I can not ignore them

Comment: Any error message in the browser console?

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: The code I want to run is basically the import of libraries like
"<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>". I have even tried to add a simple alert function, but it is not executed, after redirection.

Comment: is this `index.html` where the angular2 application is initialized from?  or is  this a template file for a specific component? Can you demonstrate the issue in a Jsfiddle example? Cause noone here wants to play a "quess what I'm thinking" kind of game.